# Convert statement to joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

please help me to write same statement using joins,

```
(SELECT isvisibleforclients FROM user_assigned_packages WHERE (user_assigned_packages.UserID = 
(SELECT ParentUserID FROM users WHERE users.UserID = UserID)))
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you need to get more than the 'isvisibleforclients' column on your result?

Comment: i have written same code in stored procedure it is giving expected result for only 1 row ,if i have more than 1 row not executing,someone told me to write in joins so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT isvisibleforclients FROM user_assigned_packages uap
JOIN users us ON
uap.UserID = us.ParentUserID
AND us.UserID = UserID
```

Assuming that **UserID** is passed in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
SELECT 
isvisibleforclients 
FROM 
user_assigned_packages a 
inner join users b on a.UserID =b.ParentUserID and  b.UserID = userID
```